# In "Great Expectations", what does this mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, literature, charles-dickens

[In Chapter 20 of *Great Expectations*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Jak0AAAAMAAJ&dq=his%20coach%20hemmed%20me%20in%20with%20a%20folding%20and%20jingling%20great%20expectations&pg=PA133#v=onepage&q&f=false), by Charles Dickens, what does the phrase I have bolded mean?

> Nevertheless, a hackney-coachman, who seemed to have as
>   many capes to his greasy great-coat as he was years old, **packed me up
>   in his coach and hemmed me in with a folding and jingling barrier of
>   steps**, as if he were going to take me fifty miles

Comment: Do you know what a "coach" is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Packed me up in his coach:**

Pack as in how you would pack something into a suitcase.

**and hemmed me in:**

Blockaded, such that the protagonist was unable to move freely. E.g.:

> The brick path to the door was hemmed in on either side by tall, unkempt boxwood hedges.

([Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/hemmed))

**with a folding and jingling barrier of steps:**

Coaches had folding steps that collapsed away when not in use, these are what is blockading the passenger against the interior of the coach.

The vocabulary is claustrophobic : *hemmed*, *pack*, and is being used to convey the sense of claustrophobia the character is experiencing in the coach.

~

Edit:

By popular consent and courtesy of Malvolio, here is a photograph depicting a coach of a similar type that Dickens is writing about here:

[image]
(Photo source: [Gail-Thornton](http://www.gail-thornton.co.uk/webyep-system/data/68-1-im-Left_hand_image-2067.jpg))

Comment: You should add that in context, the "coach" would have been a horse-drawn passenger wagon, probably enclosed [like this one](http://www.gail-thornton.co.uk/webyep-system/data/68-1-im-Left_hand_image-2067.jpg).  I think Dickens must not have liked traveling by coach: his novels have vivid depictions of how claustrophobic and unpleasant it was.